# Auto replace number from a string in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file `test.xml`, something like this:

```
<manifest XML:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="com.connect"

android:versionCode="32"

android:versionName="9.3.0.114" >
```

I want to used script to open file test.xml.
Then find string `android:versionName="9.3.0.114" >` to update automatic become `android:versionName="9.3.0.115" >`
So the last number start 100 to 999 will  `+1` dy by day.

I tried something like below but not correctly

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $test= "test.xml";
open my $fh,"<", "$test" or die $!;

while (my $srt = <$fh>) {
$str = "android:versionName=\"9.3.0.114\" >";
$str =~s/((?:[^\=]*)=\"(?:[^"]*)\.)(\d+)\"/my $ret = "$1".($2+1)."\""; ($ret);/ge;
print $srt;
}
close($fh);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Some thing you have to try...

Comment: what about `119`

Answer (score 2):

Please - don't use regular expressions to hack XML. It's brittle. XML is contextual, and regular expressions are not.

But this is surprisingly easy using a real parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'test.xml')

foreach my $manifest ( $twig -> findnodes ( '//manifest' ) ) {
    my @version = split /\./, $manifest->att('android:versionName');
    $version[-1]++;   #or whatever mechanism you want to use to update
    $manifest -> set_att('android:versionName', join ".", @version );
}

$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$twig -> print;

open ( my $output, '>', 'test_new.xml') or die $!;
print {$output} $twig -> sprint;
```

Answer (score -2):

Just a simple regex makes fine (I have updated your code here):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Tie::File;

my $infile = 'test.xml';
my @lines;

tie(@lines, 'Tie::File', $infile) or die("can't open $infile: $!");

$srt = join "\n", @lines;
$srt=~s/(android\:versionName=\"(?:[^"]*)\.)(\d+)\"/my $ret = "$1".($2+1)."\""; ($ret);/ge;

@lines = split /\n/, $srt;

untie @lines;
```

Input `test.xml`:

```
<manifest XML:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.connect"
android:versionCode="32"
android:versionName="9.3.0.114">

<manifest XML:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.connect"
android:versionCode="32"
android:versionName="9.3.0.200">
```

Output:

```
<manifest XML:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.connect"
android:versionCode="32"
android:versionName="9.3.0.115">

<manifest XML:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.connect"
android:versionCode="32"
android:versionName="9.3.0.201">
```

**However if you are using fully XML based process so then you will try `XML::Twig` as better output.**

Comment: Hi sir, I set @lastnumber = (100..999) and edit $str = "android:versionName=\"9.3.0.$lastnumber[0]\"";
So It was not working. Because the last number always changed day by day. Please help me.

Comment: I am wonder on your question. Its regex and its not hard coded.

Comment: `for(100..999) {  print "android:versionName=\"9.3.0.$_\";\n";  }`

Comment: Actually, the script will be changed number as I need, but not save in test.xml. 
I has tried add permission read,write as:
from open my $fh,"<", "$test" or die $!; 
to open my $fh,"+<", "$test" or die $!;
but nothing happen.

Comment: Downvoted for encouraging parsing XML with regular expressions.

Comment: @DaveCross: That's why I have advised OP to use the `XML::Twig`. No issues champs.

Comment: But the example code in your answer doesn't use XML::Twig, it uses a regex. And that's a terrible idea. Please don't do that.